# ClassNotFound in Eclipse on Spring config files with a Spring multi-module maven project

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, m2e

We have an issue in Eclipse/STS with a Spring multi-module maven project which can be described as follows:

- The project has a parent pom with two modules: a jar and a war. The war sees the jar.
- None of the classes referenced in the spring configuration files are resolved by Eclipse. e.g. `<bean class="com.ourcompany.OurClass" ...` and therefore we get class not found in the Eclipse IDE
- However the application runs fine when built manually with maven (mvn package/install)

Can anyone please provide advice?

FYI, we use STS 2.9.1

Comment: How did you import your project into Eclipse?

Comment: Hi. Import>maven>existing maven project.